# python: Accessing an instance variable using a name containing a variable

Tags: python, variables, instance

in python I'm trying to access a instance variable where I need to use the value of another variable to determine the name:  Example Instance Variable: user.remote.directory where it point to the value of 'servername:/mnt/.....' and user portion contains the userid of the user, such as joe.remote.directory

from another class I need to be able to access the joe.remote.directory using a variable that contains the user id of joe.  I tried variable.remote.directory  but it doesn't work, any suggestions?

Comment: There's almost always a better way to do this. While Python does allow you to access variables using string names, it's really kludgy and can actually *slow down* your whole program (when Python detects that you're doing this, it has to turn off a whole bunch of optimisations that it could otherwise do).

Answer (score 15):

Unsure quite what you want, but I think `getattr(obj, 'name')` might help. See http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr

Answer (score 8):

You can refer to instance variable called `name` of object `obj` this way:

```
obj.__dict__['name']
```

Therefore, if you have another variable `prop` which holds the name of the instance variable you'd like to refer to, you can do it this way:

```
obj.__dict__[prop]
```

If you find yourself needing this functionality, you should ask yourself whether it isn't in fact a good circumstance to use an instance of `dict` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you create an extra User-Object, which you pass to the appropriate Objects or functions as needed. You are being extremly vague, so it's hard to give you a more practical advice.

Example:

```
class User:
   def __init__(self, name, uid=None, remote=None, dir=None):
       self.name = name
       self.uid = uid
       self.remote = remote
       self.directory = dir

   def get_X(self)
       ...

   def create_some_curios_String(self):
       """ for uid = 'joe', remote='localhost' and directory = '/mnt/srv'
           this method would return the string:
           'joe@localhost://mnt/srv'
       """
       return '%s@%s:/%s' % (self.uid, self.remote, self.directory)


class AnotherClass:
    def __init__(self, user_obj):
        self.user = user_obj

class YetAnotherClass:
    def getServiceOrFunctionalityForUser(self, user):
        doWhatEverNeedsToBeDoneWithUser(user)
        doWhatEverNeedsToBeDoneWithUserUIDandRemote(user.uid, user.remote)

joe = User('Joe Smith', 'joe', 'localhost', '/mnt/srv')
srv_service = ServerService(joe.create_some_curios_String())
srv_service.do_something_super_important()
```